# Where is the boost converter in Cypress PSOC 5LP CY8CKIT-059 Prototyping kit?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, psoc

I have been using the boost converter (dc-dc converter) of "PSOC CY8CKIT-050 development kit" for a time, but I wanted to use the one in PSOC CY8CKIT-059. Nevertheless, I didn't find the boost converter in the schematics ([schematic](https://www.cypress.com/file/443786/download)), thus I don't know where measure to check its behaviour. I thought that this PSOC hadn't a boost converter, but when I programm it in PSOC creator, I can add a boost converter as usual, so I suppose it has one.

I hope someone can help me. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't available.

The target part on that board has the *capability* to act as a boost converter, but is not connected as one -- the IND pin is not connected, and the VBAT and VBOOST pins are wired to VSS. This disables the boost converter, making it unusable on this board.

The intended implementation for the boost converter is shown on page 12 of [the PSoC BoostConv reference](https://www.cypress.com/file/127686/download#page=12).

Comment: Then, if I program it as a boost converter, where should I measure in order to test its behaviour?

Comment: Nowhere, because it won't work.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much